# Prove that for $n \geq 3$, there exists a prime factor of $F_n$ which is larger than $2^{n+2}(n+1)$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$n$ is a positive integer, $F_n=2^{2^{n}}+1$. Prove that for $n \geq 3$, there exists a prime factor of $F_n$ which is larger than $2^{n+2}(n+1)$.

I want to use orders and Zsigmondy. I really don't know to use it. I thought of using something similar. That is considering a prime $p|2^{2^{n}}+1.$ We get $p|2^{2^{n+1}}-1.$ So $ord_p{2}=2^{n+1}|p-1.$

Comment: FYI, at the bottom of the [Other theorems about Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers) section, there's Édouard Lucas's theorem that, for $n \gt 1$, all prime factors of $F_n$ are of the form $k2^{n+2} + 1$.